# Android Recycleview App crash

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-recyclerview

[image]

I'm trying to make a recycle view and I'm also using tab layout in my app. I followed a tutorial step by step but I don't know why it crashes. Here's the code. I guess there's a problem with this part:

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return herosList.size();
    }
```

Whenever I change return to 0 the app will run but nothing will appear in the `recycleview`

```
public class Heros {
    public String name;
    public int img;

}
```

RecycleAdapter.java

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;    
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.HerosViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Heros> herosList;
    public RecycleAdapter(ArrayList<Heros> heross){
        herosList=heross;
    }

    @Override
    public HerosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.eachrow,parent,false);
        return new HerosViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HerosViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Heros heros=herosList.get(position);
        holder.txtName.setText(heros.name);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return herosList.size();
    }

    public class HerosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView herosImg;
        public TextView txtName;
        public HerosViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            herosImg=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgg);
            txtName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHerosName);


        }
    }
}



public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager manager;
    String[] names={"abs","vline","chest"};

    ArrayList<Heros> passName;

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        passName=new ArrayList<>();


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container,
                false);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rec);
        manager=new LinearLayoutManager(G.context);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
            Heros heros=new Heros();
            heros.name=names[i];
            passName.add(heros);
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecycleAdapter(passName));


        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you getting ?

Comment: Add the stacktrace of crash

Comment: show your logcat

Comment: use this keyword  in this method  `public RecycleAdapter(ArrayList<Heros> heross){
        this.herosList=heross;
    }`

Comment: Any stacktrace ?? Share your log !

Comment: What is `G.context` ?

Comment: The stack trace you've posted does not appear to match the code in your question. Please make sure to provide your current code exactly as it is, and a stack trace that's current, as well.

Comment: Please refrain from adding please-help-me or other begging messages to your questions, especially in titles. We like succinct here.

Answer (score 0):

check this it might help you 
        public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

```
private int mPage;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
LinearLayoutManager manager;
String[] names={"abs","vline","chest"};

ArrayList<Heros> passName;
RecycleAdapter adapter;
public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    passName=new ArrayList<>();


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container,
            false);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rec);
    manager=new LinearLayoutManager(G.context);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        Heros heros=new Heros();
        heros.name=names[i];
        passName.add(heros);
    }
 RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
adapter = new RecycleAdapter(this,passName);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When u return 0 in  `getItemCount()`  it indicate that there are 0 items in RecyclerView. That's why u cant see anything in `RecyclerView`.

However the problem you are facing might be due to adapter is receiving wrong data...

Answer (score -1):

Try to change

```
 manager=new LinearLayoutManager(G.context);
```

To

```
manager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```